# Plotting two sets of data on the same axes using Holoviews

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, holoviews

I created a dataframe as follows:

```
Waves1        Waves2       Data1     Data2_1     Data2_2
100           100          0.05      0.10       0.20
101           110          0.075     0.50       0.75
102           125          0.10      0.75       0.96
 .             .            .         .          . 
 .             .            .         .          .
```

I want to use Holoviews to plot overlaying graphs where the x-axis is Waves (both 1 and 2 since they are the same kind of data just corresponding different datasets).

The code that I have so far:

```
vdims = [('Data1', 'Data1'),('Data2_1','Data2.1'),('Data2_2','Data2.2')]
ds = hv.Dataset(new_df, ['Waves1', 'Waves2'], vdims)

curve_opts = dict(height=300, width = 600, tools=['hover'], xrotation=90, color=hv.Cycle(['lightseagreen','blue','indianred','coral']),  line_width=0.5)

curve = hv.Curve(new_df, 'Waves1','Data1')*hv.Curve(new_df, 'Waves2','Data2_1')
layout = curve.options({'Curve':curve_opts})

plot = hv.renderer('bokeh').get_plot(layout)
hv.ipython.display(plot)
```

I get the following graph where one axis ends and the other begins after that (please ignore the difference in labels/values). Also, the x-axis is messed up-it shows every value instead of a proper scale.

[image]

Comment: Could you report the dtypes of your data? I suspect the numbers are actually stored as strings and to get a meaningful plot you'll have to convert them to floats.

Comment: @philippjfr type(df['Waves']) prints:  <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: What does df.dtypes print?

Comment: In fact simply try casting everything to floats with df = df.astype('float') and then try plotting again.

Comment: @philippjfr that worked!!! THANK YOU!